# Best practices for catching exceptions from SQL in C#

Tags: c#, sql, exception

What are some good ways to catch business logic exceptions or return values from SQL in C#?  For instance, upon creating a new user, if the user already exists, the system and the user must be notified.  I have used the `raise_error()` method with a particular state int value, I have used a stored procedure returning int values, and I have also selected a msg column with a particular structure. Are there any best practices for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i always do two things:

1. use raiseerror, which manifests on the code side as an exception, and
2. return an error code

this lets me catch errors both in C# code and also when one stored procedure calls another

[sql server now supports a try-catch block, but i haven't used it yet]